# How to resolve conflicting distributions in apt-get

Tags: apt, 17.04, plex

When doing an apt-get update/upgrade I see that warning

```
W: Conflicting distribution: https://downloads.plex.tv/repo/deb public InRelease (expected public but got )
```

I was upgrading to Ubuntu Zesty 17.04 before and do not know how to fix the above. Already have seen https://forums.plex.tv/discussion/162337/plex-media-server-ppa-for-ubuntu/p4? but there are no suggested fixes for that.

Maybe one of you can give some hints? Thanks!

Comment: Its a warning message (`W`) not an error(`E`), nothing is broken, but the message seems to be truncated. Can you please try to get the whole message.

Comment: ok, changed to warning. and i am afraid, this is the whole message, not truncated. indeed it's weird that there is nothing after "got"

Answer (score 3):

I encountered the same problem on Ubuntu 18.04 (Bionic). I fixed the problem by deleting the file `plexmedeaserver.list` from `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/`.

Am guessing these are appended to the main sources.list when you execute apt-get update. If I ever need to update Plex, I can manually add the update source to get that done.

Comment: Renaming the file to something not ending in `.list` (e.g. `.list.bak`) should suffice.