# Conflicting package errors!

Tags: apt, updates

When I do

```
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

I get these errors below:

```
Hit:1 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease
Hit:2 http://ppa.launchpad.net/git-core/ppa/ubuntu disco InRelease                                                                                                      
Hit:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy InRelease                                                                                                                 
Ign:4 http://repo.vivaldi.com/stable/deb stable InRelease                                                                                                               
Ign:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy-updates InRelease                                                                                                         
Hit:7 http://repo.vivaldi.com/stable/deb stable Release                                                                                                                 
Hit:8 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu focal InRelease                                                                                                          
Hit:5 https://cli-assets.heroku.com/branches/stable/apt ./ InRelease                                                                                                    
Hit:9 http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt groovy-pgdg InRelease                                                                                                     
Ign:10 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy-backports InRelease                                                                                                      
Ign:11 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy-security InRelease                                                              
Hit:12 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy-updates Release                                                                                              
Hit:13 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy-backports Release                                                                                            
Hit:14 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy-security Release                                                                
Hit:15 https://download.sublimetext.com apt/stable/ InRelease                                
Hit:16 https://packagecloud.io/AtomEditor/atom/any any InRelease       
Reading package lists... Done
W: Conflicting distribution: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy InRelease (expected groovy but got groovy-pgdg)
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'main/binary-i386/Packages' as repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'i386'
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'restricted/binary-amd64/Packages' as repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy InRelease' doesn't have the component 'restricted' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'restricted/binary-i386/Packages' as repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy InRelease' doesn't have the component 'restricted' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'restricted/i18n/Translation-en' as repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy InRelease' doesn't have the component 'restricted' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'restricted/i18n/Translation-en_US' as repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy InRelease' doesn't have the component 'restricted' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'restricted/dep11/Components-amd64.yml' as repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy InRelease' doesn't have the component 'restricted' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'restricted/dep11/icons-48x48.tar' as repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy InRelease' doesn't have the component 'restricted' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'restricted/dep11/icons-64x64.tar' as repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy InRelease' doesn't have the component 'restricted' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'restricted/dep11/icons-64x64@2.tar' as repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy InRelease' doesn't have the component 'restricted' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'restricted/cnf/Commands-amd64' as repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy InRelease' doesn't have the component 'restricted' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'universe/binary-amd64/Packages' as repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy InRelease' doesn't have the component 'universe' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'universe/binary-i386/Packages' as repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy InRelease' doesn't have the component 'universe' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'universe/i18n/Translation-en_US' as repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy InRelease' doesn't have the component 'universe' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'universe/i18n/Translation-en' as repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy InRelease' doesn't have the component 'universe' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'universe/dep11/Components-amd64.yml' as repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy InRelease' doesn't have the component 'universe' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'universe/dep11/icons-48x48.tar' as repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy InRelease' doesn't have the component 'universe' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'universe/dep11/icons-64x64.tar' as repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy InRelease' doesn't have the component 'universe' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'universe/dep11/icons-64x64@2.tar' as repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy InRelease' doesn't have the component 'universe' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'universe/cnf/Commands-amd64' as repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy InRelease' doesn't have the component 'universe' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'multiverse/binary-i386/Packages' as repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy InRelease' doesn't have the component 'multiverse' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'multiverse/binary-amd64/Packages' as repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy InRelease' doesn't have the component 'multiverse' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'multiverse/i18n/Translation-en_US' as repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy InRelease' doesn't have the component 'multiverse' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'multiverse/i18n/Translation-en' as repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy InRelease' doesn't have the component 'multiverse' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'multiverse/dep11/Components-amd64.yml' as repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy InRelease' doesn't have the component 'multiverse' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'multiverse/dep11/icons-48x48.tar' as repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy InRelease' doesn't have the component 'multiverse' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'multiverse/dep11/icons-64x64.tar' as repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy InRelease' doesn't have the component 'multiverse' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'multiverse/dep11/icons-64x64@2.tar' as repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy InRelease' doesn't have the component 'multiverse' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'multiverse/cnf/Commands-amd64' as repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy InRelease' doesn't have the component 'multiverse' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

And below i have my sources.list

```
# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS _Bionic Beaver_ - Release amd64 (20180725)]/ disco main restricted
# # See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy main restricted
# deb-src http://se.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ disco main restricted
## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy-updates main restricted
# deb-src http://se.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ disco-updates main restricted
## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy universe
# deb-src http://se.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ disco universe
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy-updates universe
# deb-src http://se.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ disco-updates universe
## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy multiverse
# deb-src http://se.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ disco multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy-updates multiverse
# deb-src http://se.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ disco-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy-backports main restricted universe multiverse
# deb-src http://se.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ disco-backports main restricted universe multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
# deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu disco partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu disco partner

deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy-security main restricted
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-security main restricted
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy-security universe
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-security universe
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy-security multiverse
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-security multiverse
# deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu focal stable # disabled on upgrade to eoan disabled on upgrade to focal
# deb-src [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu disco stable
# deb [arch=amd64] https://packagecloud.io/AtomEditor/atom/any/ any main # disabled on upgrade to eoan disabled on upgrade to focal
deb-src [arch=amd64] https://packagecloud.io/AtomEditor/atom/any/ any main # disabled on upgrade to focal disabled on upgrade to groovy
deb https://cli-assets.heroku.com/branches/stable/apt ./ # disabled on upgrade to eoan disabled on upgrade to groovy
# deb-src https://cli-assets.heroku.com/branches/stable/apt ./
# deb https://deb.torproject.org/torproject.org focal main # disabled on upgrade to eoan disabled on upgrade to focal
# deb https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ focal main # disabled on upgrade to eoan disabled on upgrade to focal
# deb-src https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ disco main
# deb [trusted=yes] https://repo.vivaldi.com/archive/deb/ stable main # disabled on upgrade to eoan disabled on upgrade to focal
# deb-src https://repo.vivaldi.com/deb [trusted=yes] https://repo.vivaldi.com/archive/deb/ stable mainarchive/deb/ stable main
# deb-src https://repo.vivaldi.com/archive/deb/ stable main
# deb-src [arch=amd64] https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode stable main
# deb-src [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu disco stable
# deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu disco stable
# deb-src [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu disco stable
# deb-src https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ focal main # disabled on upgrade to focal
# deb-src https://repo.vivaldi.com/archive/deb/ stable main
# deb [arch=i386,amd64] http://repo.vivaldi.com/stable/deb/ stable main
# deb-src [arch=i386,amd64] http://repo.vivaldi.com/stable/deb/ stable main
# deb-src [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu eoan stable
# deb-src [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu eoan stable
# deb-src https://repo.vivaldi.com/archive/deb/ stable main
# deb-src [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu focal stable
# deb http://apt.kubernetes.io/ kubernetes-xenial main # disabled on upgrade to groovy
# deb-src http://apt.kubernetes.io/ kubernetes-xenial main
```

How can i solve these errors or is it something with my hardware?

Comment: A more representative title would be appropriate. Otherwise, 20% of the questions would bear the same title...

Comment: Did you manually edit your sources file ? Please **edit** your question and add the contents of your `sources.list` file. It looks like something is not well written or configured in it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43857550/how-to-resolve-conflicting-distributions-in-apt-get

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/913211/how-to-resolve-conflicting-distributions-in-apt-get

Comment: Please tell us what you looked for and found, what you tried, etc.

Comment: You haven't provided your OS & specifically release, but as most lines appear to contain *groovy* in them, why are you using *disco* for one or more??  Using an older release can cause conflicting package errors

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No one seems to give an answer to my question so i will provide an answer here below:

Type these commands below and the warnings did disappear:

```
sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/* -vf

sudo apt-get clean

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get upgrade
```

The links they gave me in the comments didn't solve my problem :(!

Comment: I'm confused: How did `apt-get clean` help fix the problem?

Comment: Remove packages from cache!